# Smoothing time seriesm, taking into account seasonality

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My time series has the following figure showing outliers:

[image: X-axis is date and Y-axis is Load]

What the best way to smooth the time series in python pandas taking into consideration seasonality.

The intended result as below:

[image]

Time series sample:

```
   dat_time            system_load
01-01-2013  00:00:00        200
01-01-2013  00:00:00        210
01-01-2013  00:00:00        230
  ...
31-12-2013  21:00:00        500
31-12-2013  22:00:00        220
31-12-2013  23:00:00        200
       ...
01-01-2020  00:00:00        300
01-01-2020  00:00:00        310
01-01-2020  00:00:00        730
      ...
31-12-2020  21:00:00        350
31-12-2020  22:00:00        270
31-12-2020  23:00:00        280
```

Comment: Is your series index one of either a `DatetimeIndex` or `TimedeltaIndex`?

Comment: My time series has always Datetime index and sometimes is only date

Comment: In the future on Stack Overflow, you'll need to supply some sample data as well as a description or some code showing what you've tried so far to get someone to provide a solution.  I'll have a quick go at a solution, here, however because I think it's an interesting question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you're asking about is called "time-series anomaly detection," and it's a real-world problem with significant scientific and business applications.  For a great overview of available libraries in modern programming languages (including Python), I recommend [awesome-TS-anomaly-detection](https://github.com/rob-med/awesome-TS-anomaly-detection).

To answer your question truthfully, there isn't really a convenient, `pandas`-only way to accomplish this task.  There are so many choices and assumptions to be made with varying tradeoffs and so many approaches to a solution, that it doesn't make sense to try to simplify it for a library as general as `pandas`.

Here is one VERY crude solution using only `pandas` and `numpy` functionality.  From a statistics perspective, it is overly simplified, not robust, and makes a lot of assumptions about your data and the nature of the problem.  However, it appears to generally answer your question.

1. Generate synthetic data that looks kind of like yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 500
num_outliers = 50

sin_x = pd.Series(np.sin(0.05*x - np.pi / 2) + 25 for x in range(size))

noise_s = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=size))

outlier_x = np.random.randint(0,size - 2, num_outliers)
outlier_y = np.random.uniform(-3.0, 10.0, num_outliers)
outliers = pd.Series(outlier_y, index=outlier_x)

date_idx = pd.date_range(start='20170101', end='20200101', periods=size)
data_vals = (noise_s + sin_x).add(outliers, fill_value=0).values[:size]
data = pd.Series(data=data_vals, index=date_idx)

# Plot
ax1 = data.plot()
ax1.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: noisy time series data with outliers]

2. Since your seasonality looks yearly, find the rolling average with a window that is roughly a couple of months wide.  For some applications, this may be close to what you want already.  I took your question literally to mean "only get rid of outliers," so let's move past this to simply filter the original data.

The `window_param` can be adjusted: larger values make narrower windows.  A good balance is usually when the plot rolling average plot is somewhat smooth but the periodic nature is still strongly visible.

```
window_param = 12  # adjustable
window = int(np.round(size / window_param))
rolling_ave = data.rolling(window=window, center=True).sum().dropna() / window

# Plot
ax2 = rolling_ave.plot()
ax2.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: rolling average of times series data]

3. Find the difference of the data and the rolling average.  Note that the very beginning and end of the time series did not get subtracted because there weren't enough surrounding points to fit the rolling average window.

```
diff = data.subtract(rolling_ave, fill_value=0)

# Plot
ax3 = diff.plot()
ax3.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: difference between time series data and rolling average]

4. Remove outliers where the absolute value of `diff` is greater than the standard deviation (excluding the beginning and end bits that didn't get subtracted in step 3). This is the part that is statistically cringe-worthy, but it's practical.  `std_param` is an adjustable parameter.  Larger values remove fewer values, and smaller values remove more values.

```
std_param_1 = 1.0  # adjustable
data_outliers_removed = data[(diff.abs() < diff[rolling_ave.index].std() * std_param)]

# Plot
ax4 = data_outliers_removed.plot()
ax4.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: time series outliers removed]

[Optional] 5. Put back the original end data, and remove outliers from this section with a similar standard deviation criterion.  Once again, `std_param_2` is adjustable.  Larger values remove fewer outliers.

```
std_param_2 = 2.0  # adjustable
data_begin = data[data.index < rolling_ave.index[0]]
data_end = data[data.index > rolling_ave.index[-1]]
data_capped = pd.concat([data_begin, data_outliers_removed, data_end])
data_w_ends = data_capped[(data_capped - data_capped.mean()).abs() < data_outliers_removed.std() * std_param_2]

# Plot
ax5 = data_w_ends.plot()
ax5.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: time series data w end put back]

[Optional] 6. Fill the holes created by eliminating outlier data by performing linear interpolation from surrounding points.  There are too many data points for this to be obvious in the plot.  This step can be useful if your application needs data with a regularly spaced index and without `NaN` values.

```
data_holey = data_w_ends.reindex(data.index)
data_patched = data_holey.interpolate()

# Plot
ax6 = data_patched.plot()
ax6.set_ylim(data.min() - 1, data.max() + 1)
```

[image: Final time series data w gaps filled]

Comment: Seriously the Code is quietly useful for monthly data but for Hourly data crops more from fundamental data -data without outliers- . I don't know if by adjusting window the result is ok or not.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, @saadawad.  I've very slightly modified the code and added notes in the answer above to let you know which parameters you can consider adjusting.

Comment: I would like to send you the figures @Fronder -Figure-1 shows the original data and Figure-2 shows the processed data using your code-noting that the data is hourly data and I apply the size =8760 *12  so I don't know how can I send them.

Comment: Seems like this has moved beyond the type of support that is helpful for the SO community.  You can find the best way to contact me directly by clicking on my username.